Alinear columna en Python
Estoy tratando de que las columnas salgan todas alineadas, pero no termino de ver como, los valores de las filas 1, 4 y 9 son mucho más pequeños que el resto y con un salto de tabulador "\t" no logro el efecto deseado.
Dejo aquí el código por si alguien puede ayudarme:
import math
import sys

def mysqrt(x):
    a = x

    while True:
        y = (x + a/x) / 2
        if abs(y-x) < sys.float_info.epsilon:
            break
        x = y

    return x

def test_square_root():
    x = 1
    print("a   mysqrt(a)            math.sqrt(a)            diff")
    print("-   ---------            ------------            ----")
    while(x < 10):
        a = mysqrt(x)
        b = math.sqrt(x)
        print(x, " ", a, "\t", b, "\t", abs(a-b))
        x+= 1


test_square_root()

Output
a   mysqrt(a)            math.sqrt(a)            diff
-   ---------            ------------            ----
1   1    1.0     0.0
2   1.414213562373095    1.4142135623730951      2.220446049250313e-16
3   1.7320508075688772   1.7320508075688772      0.0
4   2.0      2.0     0.0
5   2.23606797749979     2.23606797749979    0.0
6   2.449489742783178    2.449489742783178   0.0
7   2.6457513110645907   2.6457513110645907      0.0
8   2.82842712474619     2.8284271247461903      4.440892098500626e-16
9   3.0      3.0     0.0


Puedes utilizar el método format().
En esta parte del código {:<21}, el número 21 define el ancho de la columna y el signo < es para alinear a la izquierda el texto cuando imprima en la consola, también puedes utilizar el signo de > para alinear a la derecha, pero este caso esta bien a la izquierda.
Solución:
import math
import sys

def mysqrt(x):
    a = x

    while True:
        y = (x + a/x) / 2
        if abs(y-x) < sys.float_info.epsilon:
            break
        x = y

    return x

def test_square_root():
    x = 1
    print("{:<2} {:<21} {:<21} {:<5}".format("a", "mysqrt(a)", "math.sqrt(a)", "diff"))
    print("{:<2} {:<21} {:<21} {:<5}".format("-", "---------", "------------", "----"))
    while(x < 10):
        a = mysqrt(x)
        b = math.sqrt(x)
        print("{:<2} {:<21} {:<21} {:<5}".format(x, a, b, abs(a-b)))
        x+= 1

test_square_root()


Resultado:
python example.py

a  mysqrt(a)             math.sqrt(a)          diff 
-  ---------             ------------          ---- 
1  1                     1.0                   0.0  
2  1.414213562373095     1.4142135623730951    2.220446049250313e-16
3  1.7320508075688772    1.7320508075688772    0.0  
4  2.0                   2.0                   0.0  
5  2.23606797749979      2.23606797749979      0.0  
6  2.449489742783178     2.449489742783178     0.0  
7  2.6457513110645907    2.6457513110645907    0.0  
8  2.82842712474619      2.8284271247461903    4.440892098500626e-16
9  3.0                   3.0                   0.0  


Muchos gracias, es justo lo que buscaba
